# Render & Rendered concepts

Tags: jsf, richfaces, render

Can any one explain me what the main purpose of ***render*** and ***rendered*** attributes in all JSF, RichFaces component ?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSF, components from your Facelets are created on server, forming some kind of component tree. Most of these components should be rendered in HTML in some way, and that is role of ***Renderer***. It will create HTML code which represents that component.

***rendered*** attribute is available on components which can be rendered. It is `boolean` attribute and if it is `true` (which is as I know always `true` by default) that component will be rendered, and its HTML will be sent to clients browser. If it is `false` that component will not be rendered in clients browser.

Answer (score 3):

In java server faces, **render** is an attribute of a JSF component using which we can load one or more other components on completion of the specific action .

**rendered** is another property of a JSF components which will have a boolean value, based on which the component will be rendered . If rendered is true then the component will be rendered , otherwise not .